# Appending column with same key within a file

Tags: awk, sed, cut

I need some formatting for my file to append the columns of then line to another with same specific column. The column that need to match are 1st column(numbers) and Type (Sword_SC, Fire_ball_sc, Fire_sc). Note that if the 1st column and timestamp was the same but the Type like 'FIRE%' they still need to combine as 1 liner.

Really appreciate your help.

SAMPLE FILE:

```
09123456789|Alarm|Alarm 2020-04-15 00:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1
09123456789|Alarm|Alarm 2020-04-15 04:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1
09123456789|Alarm|Alarm 2020-04-15 15:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1
09123456789|Alarm|Alarm 2020-04-15 16:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1
09123456789|Alarm|Alarm 2020-04-15 20:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1
09222222222|Alarm|Alarm 2020-04-15 00:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1
09222222222|Alarm|Alarm 2020-04-15 04:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1
09222222222|Alarm|Alarm 2020-04-15 15:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1
09222222222|Alarm|Alarm 2020-04-15 16:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1
09222222222|Alarm|Alarm 2020-04-15 20:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1
09555555555|Alarm|Alarm 2020-04-15 20:59:59^Breached Threshold^FIRE_BALL_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1
09555555555|Alarm|Alarm 2020-04-15 20:59:59^Breached Threshold^FIRE_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1
```

DESIRE OUTPUT

```
09123456789|Alarm|Alarm 2020-04-15 00:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1^^Alarm 2020-04-15 04:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1^^Alarm 2020-04-15 15:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1^^Alarm 2020-04-15 16:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1^^Alarm 2020-04-15 20:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1
09222222222|Alarm|Alarm 2020-04-15 00:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1^^Alarm 2020-04-15 04:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1^^Alarm 2020-04-15 15:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1^^Alarm 2020-04-15 16:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1^^Alarm 2020-04-15 20:59:59^Breached Threshold^Sword_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1
09555555555|Alarm|Alarm 2020-04-15 20:59:59^Breached Threshold^FIRE_BALL_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1^^Alarm 2020-04-15 20:59:59^Breached Threshold^FIRE_SC @ 0.0 ^Sample Size: 1
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Apology, cause I don't have any idea to construct the script that's why i'm seeking for your help @ArkadiuszDrabczyk

Comment: Nobody is going to manually copy your example to an editor.

Comment: Done editing @ArkadiuszDrabczyk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU awk

```
gawk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '
  {
    n = split($3, fields, /\^/)
    key = $1 substr(fields[3], 1, 4)
    alarms[key] = alarms[key] sep[key] $3
    sep[key] = "^^"
  }
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (key in alarms) print gensub(/....$/, "", 1, key), "Alarm", alarms[key]
  }
' file
```

Comment: Perfectly this solution works well. Can I get some explanation?

Comment: If you're not sure how awk works, in general, start with the [tag:awk] tag info page [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/awk/info) or [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info). Do you have questions about any specific part of my answer?